# how to fix Host bindings are not valid on ng-container

Tags: angular, express, angular-universal

after I build my Angular 10 project using `ng build` I got this error.

```
ASSERTION ERROR: Attempted to set attribute `dir` on a container node. 
Host bindings are not valid on ng-container or ng-template. 
[Expected=> false == true <=Actual]

    at throwError (D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\@eng-dibo\ngx\dist\cms\core\server\express.js:49455:11)
    at assertEqual (D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\@eng-dibo\ngx\dist\cms\core\server\express.js:49406:9)
    at assertNodeNotOfTypes (D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\@eng-dibo\ngx\dist\cms\core\server\express.js:52043:5)
    at elementAttributeInternal (D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\@eng-dibo\ngx\dist\cms\core\server\express.js:56997:9)
    at Module.ɵɵattribute (D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\@eng-dibo\ngx\dist\cms\core\server\express.js:62733:9)
    at Dir_HostBindings (D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\@eng-dibo\ngx\dist\cms\core\server\express.js:48225:66)
    at setHostBindingsByExecutingExpandoInstructions (D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\@eng-dibo\ngx\dist\cms\core\server\express.js:55806:25)
    at refreshView (D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\@eng-dibo\ngx\dist\cms\core\server\express.js:56081:9)
    at refreshComponent (D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\@eng-dibo\ngx\dist\cms\core\server\express.js:57182:13)
    at refreshChildComponents (D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\@eng-dibo\ngx\dist\cms\core\server\express.js:55843:9)
```

note: I'm using Angular-universal with express

[repo](https://github.com/eng-dibo/ngx/tree/master/projects/cms)

Comment: are you using ng-container? and if so, what does it look like?

Comment: yes, I do. this is the file where I mainly use ng-container and ng-template. 

https://github.com/eng-dibo/ngx/blob/master/packages/ngx-content-view/view.html